# How can I get the title attribute from get_the_post_thumbnail()?

Tags: themes, pages, post-thumbnails

In my theme I want to display the featured image, but I also want to display the title attribute (of the image, not of the post/page) beside the image itself.

Is there a simple way to do this? Where should I be looking?

Thanks,
John.

Comment: Can you mark your question as answered since you found the solution. You can answer your own question. This removes it from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 23):

post_excerpt is actually the caption attribute. Here is the correct answer:

```
$title = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_title; //The Title
$caption = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; //The Caption
$description = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_content; // The Description
```

Comment: This is an accurate answer and must be upvoted.

Comment: Dear god my eyes are bleeding. Sadly that's the right answer, in Wordpress everything and their mother is a post.

Comment: `get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_title` (in contrast to @mfgmicha's the_post_thumbnail_caption()) displays filename without extension, not the text entered into "Title" field in media gallery

Answer (score 4):

Easy!

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail();
echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?>
```

Taken from: http://www.billerickson.net/wordpress-featured-image-captions/

Answer (score 2):

Since WordPress 4.6 there are new functions for the post thumbnail caption

Get caption text: ([Doc link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_caption/))

```
// return the caption text without any html markup
get_the_post_thumbnail_caption();
```

Output caption text: ([Doc link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_caption/))

```
// echo the caption text without any html markup
the_post_thumbnail_caption();
```

You can add a specific post as object or id as parameter. Without (like shown above) WordPress uses the current post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get thumbnail title:

```
echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_title;
```

Don't forget to add open and close PHP tag.

Comment: Are you certain this gets the *title* attribute of a post thumbnail?